# How to setState while not changing the text?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So I transport the `job` object from one page to another.
I get the object like this inside render;

```
const { job } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
```

Outside render I have this function that I call when I `submit`

```
onJobPost = () => {
    var { category } = this.state;
    var { title } = this.state;
}
```

Now here is my `TextInput` where as you can see I display the content of `job.title`.

```
<TextInput
  onChangeText={(title) => { this.setState({ title }) }} placeholder="Job Title"
  style={{ fontSize: 20, paddingLeft: 40, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{job.title}</TextInput>
```

My question is how do I use `job.title` to set the state without changing anything inside `TextInput`.

For example `job.title` is `New job here` and I will edit just category input. This one I will not touch but because there is some text inside I will use it to set the state.

```
<TextInput
  onChangeText={(title) => { this.setState({ title }) }} placeholder="Job Title"
  style={{ fontSize: 20, paddingLeft: 40, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>New job here</TextInput>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Could you elaborate on what you mean by "how do I use `job.title` to set the state without changing anything inside `TextInput`"? Also, your `onJobPost` function doesn't seem to do anything?

Comment: @Tholle so because I use this as an edit page there are two fields one is `job.category` and one is `job.title`. While `job.category` has the value of `barista` and `job.title` has the value of `Some Title` I want to change `barista` in `Barista`. Because in `title` filed I haven't changed anything but the value of `Some Title` is there I would like to use it as state for title. The function actually has a `dispatch(updateJob(category, title))`. Hope that now is more clear